# Void pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I am in initial phase of learning C language. I have one doubt regarding a statement including void pointer.

```
void (*myvar)(const struct foo *);
```

Can anyone please help me about the above line. What is the exact meaning of above line and how do use this pointer in the code.

Comment: `struct char` is an error.

Comment: this is a function pointer where 1) the function returns void, 2) the only parameter is a const.  However, the type const struct char * is probably not valid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your question,

`void (*myvar)(const struct charpp *);` <sup>Follow the NOTE</sup>

is a function pointer, not a simple `pointer -to -struct`. You can find more information regarding this [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

Also, do check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/3137699) answer for a clear idea of the usage.

Note: `char` is a reserved keyword [datatype] in c. It cannot be used as variable name, as you've used in your code. Change so something else.

Comment: @NatashaDutta But when you show some statement and say it is a function pointer it is misleading

Comment: I do understand that struct char was invalid. I was trying to give some var name, but my mistake given the char word. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

That *should* be a *variable* declaration of a pointer to a function taking a `const char *` as argument and not returning any value. I say *should* because you have an error in the declaration of the argument type (there's no such thing as `const struct char *`).

If you fix the error, and assuming you mean `const char *`, then you can use it like the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_print_line(const char *str)
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*myvar)(const char *);

    myvar = &my_print_line;

    myvar("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I do understand that struct char was invalid. I was trying to give some var name, but my mistake given the char word. Correct one : void (*myvar)(const struct foo *);

Answer (score 2):

It is a pointer to a function. You can break and understand the rule easily if you follow the [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Take a look at Example2. Now you can easily, put your declaration instead of the example and break it part by part to get better understanding.

```
             +--------------------+
             | +---+              |
             | |+-+|              |
             | |^ ||              |
        char *(*fp)( int, float *);
         ^   ^ ^  ||              |
         |   | +--+|              |
         |   +-----+              |
         +------------------------+
```

Also, `struct char` will generate an error.